# Separate table or a single table

Tags: sql, database, schema

I have two sets of data that are needed to be joined to some condition. Both have some common columns, but for one of the set, I have used non-nullable constraint on some fields which might not be present in the other set.

Should I make separate table for both sets of data or should I remove the non nullable constraint on the columns and save both sets in one table ?

(One of the set of data is sourced from pdf data and other set of data will be uploaded by the user)

**Edit**: Also , does creating index on columns in `SELECT` statement improves performance ?

Answer (score 2):

After noting the points you mentioned, I believe to keep the two sets of data in separate tables due to the non-nullable constraint on some fields in one set and the potential absence of those fields in the other set. In this way, you can also improve your data integrity.

And also using index in the select query improves query performance as it makes it easy for us to perform some operations like search.